# Django how to set user model session expiration time

Tags: django, session-cookies

So I am using the default django user model and I noticed that people seemed to be logged in by default for a week or so. I want to change that so they are logged in for like 5 years or so. Is there a way I can go in and set expiration times on the user auth session cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default django session cookie is valid for 2 weeks.

You can configure it by setting [`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age) in seconds.

For more options look at [Browser-length sessions vs. persistent sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions)